# Factorial digits sum puzzle, time complexity survey

Tags: python, python-3.x, time-complexity, asymptotic-complexity

What would you say the time-complexity of the `foo` function is (relative to `n`)?

```
DIGIT_FACTORIAL = [1]
for x in range(1, 10):
    DIGIT_FACTORIAL.append(DIGIT_FACTORIAL[x-1]*x)

def digit_factorial(x):
    return DIGIT_FACTORIAL[x]

def foo(number_of_digits):
    n = 10**number_of_digits
    i = n//9

    while i != sum(digit_factorial(int(x)) for x in str(i)) and i < n:
        i += 1

    if i < n:
        return i
    return None
```

Comment: Cross-posted: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51704940/781723, https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/41324/5038. Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Comment: What's the correct way of doing cross community posts? (So both communities have a chance to answer the question).

Comment: The correct way is to avoid doing cross community posts; the site software was not designed for that.  Instead, you should pick the one site that is the best fit for your question.  See the link I gave.  If you have two separate questions that need to be answered from two different perspectives, you can post each one at a different site (but just taking the same question and then doing slight rewording of it probably isn't the intent of that).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O(n log(n))

### Explanation:

Every `while` loop runs from `111...1 == n/9` to `n`.  This means that the while loop runs `n*8/9` times.  O(n * some_constant) == **O(n)**.

Inside each iteration, the sum is over all the digits in `i`.  There are `log10(n) - 1` digits in `i`. O(log10(n) - 1) == **O(log(n))**.

Nesting the two makes **O(n log(n))**.

Note that the above explanation does not take into account that the loop could break early if `i == sum(...)`.  That is because the upper bound for `sum(digit_factorial(int(x)) for x in str(i))` is `9! * number_of_digits` which is always less than `i` when `number_of_digits` is greater than 7 or so.

Comment: I actually missed that `i = n/9`, good catch. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: No problem!  The `n/9` thing is just a nice number trick to make the explanation a little simpler.  The important thing is realizing that the distance between `n` and `i (start)` grows linearly.  Another way you could see this is by noting that `i = 111..1` is bounded by `110..0 == 1.1 * n/10` and `120..0 == 1.2 * n/10`.